# MSSQL reportserver behind web application firewall

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, web-application-firewall

Good Morning everyone!

First, please just point me in direction, where can I look into documentation.
I should get a consultant, but as a DBA, I want to solve this issue by myself.

Issue:

- Management decision is that report server (RS) website should run behind Barracuda web application firewall (WAF)
- AD, WAF and Network are not managed by myself
- RS Server is implemented on Database Server
- Exposed url is different than RS server name and network domain name

  - public URL rsweb.company.com
  - private URL server.domain.loc with server name
- WAF does not do SSL offloading and does not have URL rewrite engine
- We need to use Kerberos
- We use different Service Accounts for DB Engine and RS services

So far i did following:

- I followed this website: https://blog.andycook.com/sql/2019/11/13/ssrs-fqdn/
- I already deployed public SSL certificate on RS Server
- RS Server has to be configured with public url
- I have to add SPNs to Service Accounts in AD
- I have to add Delegation to Computer Account in AD

Current issue:

- Website repeats user and password dialog and,
- I don't have any error messages

My questions:

- do you have any links with comprehensive documentation to "how to configure SSRS behind web application firewall"
- did you implement this kind of implementation and what issues you run in your case

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented NTLM authentication against FQDN URL, which was same as WAF URL.

Because of some issues within Baracuda WAF (not my part of job and responsibility) it took time to get it work.

End result is, WAF was just "non-SSL-Offloaded" reverse proxy, just passing connection to RS Server.

It worked, but I'm not happy with it, as it is implemented at the moment.